# Magnific Popup - Exclude hiding certain element using class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, magnific-popup

I have a jQuery UI input field in a magnific popup inline div. The autocomplete ul is being hidden along with everything else, as seen here:

[image]

(autocomplete is highlighted in yellow)

What I've been trying to do is adding the same class as the popup div to the autocomplete ul with

```
open: function () {
                    $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.addClass('white-popup');
                },
```

Which doesn't work. I was looking into how to exlcude elements from the magnific popup hide but could not find any clear answer.

Comment: Could we get a url or a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually it is the z-index that is the problem. You can try add

```
$(this).css({'z-index':1500});
```

I don't know what z-index the magnific popup is using, but looking at their site I got 1045 so something with a larger z-index should work.